# Function definition can only be called once then won't run

Tags: python, python-3.x

***NOTE: For anyone stumbling upon this thread, I highly recommend reading the article this post "duplicates". It goes into great detail why this issue is happening and lays out the design flaw of the language. TLDR; functions have elements that act like classes and will maintain data between calls, even though literally nothing in your code will tell it to do that....***

The title pretty much explains it all. I can only call the definition `processJSON` it runs perfectly, but any/all other calls to it literally doesn't do anything and it's driving me crazy. Why does it not run anymore?

```
import json
import os
import csv
import copy

def processJSON(initialDict:dict, outPut:dict = {}, createTemplate:bool = False, parentKey:str = None, sep:str ='.', skipParent:bool = False) -> dict:

    #Loop through all keeys and return unique options
    for key in initialDict.keys():

        #Create needed variables
        keyTitle = str(parentKey + sep + key if parentKey else key)

        #Loop
        if type(initialDict[key]) == dict:
            parentTitle = ('' if skipParent else keyTitle)
            outPut.update(processJSON(initialDict=initialDict[key], outPut = outPut, createTemplate = createTemplate, parentKey = parentTitle, sep = sep))
        elif keyTitle not in outPut.keys():
            print(createTemplate)
            keyValue = str('' if createTemplate == True else initialDict[key])
            outPut[keyTitle] = keyValue

    return dict(outPut)
#Basic Veriables
scriptDirectory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

#Read the JSON files.
#Library File
with open(os.path.join(scriptDirectory,'inventoryItem.json'), "r",encoding='utf-8') as read_file:
    lib = json.load(read_file)

#English Dictionary
with open(os.path.join(scriptDirectory,'en.json'), "r",encoding='utf-8') as read_file:
    en = json.load(read_file)

for key in lib['inventoryItem'].keys():
    firstItem = True
    header =  processJSON(initialDict=lib['inventoryItem'][key], createTemplate=True, skipParent=True)

    try:
        with open(os.path.join(scriptDirectory,'export',f"{key}.csv"),"w", newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:

            for item in lib['inventoryItem'][key]:
                print(item)
                
                #Copy Header because Python sucks
                row = copy.deepcopy(header)
                print(processJSON(initialDict=lib['inventoryItem'][key][item], createTemplate=False, skipParent=False))
                row.update(processJSON(initialDict=lib['inventoryItem'][key][item], createTemplate=False, skipParent=False))
                print(row)
                break
                
                print(row)
                row.update(processJSON(initialDict=lib['inventoryItem'][key][item]))
                print(row)
                if firstItem:
                    firstItem = False
                    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=header.keys(),delimiter = ';')
                    writer.writeheader()
                    
                writer.writerow(row)
                
    except IOError:
        print("I/O error")

    break
```

Comment: If you call a function, it will run. If the behavior you're expecting isn't happening, then the function isn't being called, or a logic error within the function is causing bad behavior. Have you confirmed that the function is being entered?

Comment: What *does* happen? How have you tried to debug the problem? If you put `print` statements in `processJSON`, can you confirm it's being called as expected? If you inspect the return value, does it match your expectations?

Comment: The code is pretty complex and in your last question with the same code, I asked why don't you use pandas which is going to make it simpler. I canot run your code, since I don't have the data, so I am going to assume that ` outPut:dict = {}` in your function definition is unsafe. It is better to set it to None and do outPut = outPut or {} inside the function

Comment: terminology note, you are talking about a *function*, not a "definition".

Comment: Side note: It would be nice if you respected the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) concerning the naming of the variables. Your code is hard to read now.

Comment: @tchar best I can tell that doesn't actually achieve the goal I am looking to achieve, but I moved this to a separate question because its a separate problem. I have finally figured this out and will close both questions now. Only took 2 miserable days lol.

Comment: @Matthias sorry, rewritten this about 200 times over the last day or so, this is just an easy to read format compared to PEP. If I ever move this to a public setting i'll convert it, I just find the PEP format miserable to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to run your code but you can try to:

Replace:

```
def processJSON(initialDict:dict, outPut:dict = {}, createTemplate:bool = False, parentKey:str = None, sep:str ='.', skipParent:bool = False) -> dict:
```

By: (remove `outPut` from args of your function)

```
def processJSON(initialDict:dict, createTemplate:bool = False, parentKey:str = None, sep:str ='.', skipParent:bool = False) -> dict:
    outPut = {}
```

With you actual code, you should try to `print(outPut)` at the beginning of your function. I think you could be surprised :-)

```
def processJSON(outPut={}):
    print(outPut)
    outPut['A'] = 1

print('First call')
processJSON()
print('Second call')
processJSON()
```

```
First call
{}
Second call
{'A': 1}
```

Comment: This makes literally 0 sense logically, but it works for some reason.... I am a pro at powershell, but some of these weird ass quirks with Python are driving my up a wall. There is so much awesome stuff Python can do but ugh lol. Python scoping and arguments seem like an absolute trainwreck....